# How to create objects using Entity Framework 6.0?

Tags: entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework 6.0 code first approach in my project. I have couple of entity classes as defined below

```
public class RequestTicket
{
   public long Id {get;set;}
   public string TicketNumber {get;set;}
   public Contact OwnedBy {get;set;}
   public long OwnedById {get;set;}
}

public class Contact
{
    public long Id {get;set;}
    public string name {get;set;}
}

public class RequestTicketRepository
{
    private readonly EntityContext _context;
    public RequestTicketRepository()
    {  
       _context = new EntityContext();
    }
    public AddRequestTicket(RequestTicket newTicket)
   {
       _context.RequestTickets.Add(newTicket);
       _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Here `RequestTicket` class has a property `OwnedBy` which is another class `Contact`.

When I call `AddRequestTicket` method on the repository with an instance of `RequestTicket` with an existing `Contact` object for its property `OwnedBy`, it is creating an entry in `RequestTicket` table and one entry in `Contact` table. I did not expect an entry to be created in `Contact` as I passed an existing contact object with proper id.

Can anybody tell me what should I have to do to avoid creating contact entry?

Answer (score 1):

I created a sample program with the code you provided and I did not see the issue you described. I was able to add a contact and then subsequently pull it out and assign it to a new RequestTicket. This did not result in creation of another Contact...

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var entityContext = new EntityContext())
        {
            // get existing contact (let's assume we know it is ID 1)
            var contact = entityContext.Contacts.Single(c => c.Id == 1);

            // create a new RequestTicket and assign that contact to it
            var rt = new RequestTicket {OwnedBy = contact, TicketNumber = "125"};

            // add the request ticket
            entityContext.RequestTickets.Add(rt);

            // save
            entityContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Although you didn't include it, here is the EntityContext class you referenced:

```
public class EntityContext : DbContext
{
    public IDbSet<RequestTicket> RequestTickets { get; set; }
    public IDbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}
```

Please keep in mind that there is no good reason to wrap derivations of DbContext with another "Repository" object. IDbSet already implements the repository pattern, so you are creating an unnecessary abstraction.

If you want to provide anymore details on the issue, please edit your post accordingly.

Here are some screenshots of the DB structure and data:

[image]

[image]